# Directory "/var/www/magento2/pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Protocol error

Tags: magento2

I use a vagrant env and catch this error when I change magento theme

Comment: It's permissions issue. Add permissions of pub/static/frontend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can't include '<' string in the Windows File system.

I fixed It by rename custom theme folder path.